# How to make checkbox editable in aspxgridview?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I need multiple selection of rows in a grid. I have done 1 with the selection command column, now I have inserted another check column, can anyone tell me how to make that column editable without using edit button? I am using DevExpress ASPxGridView Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can add a ItemTemplate under Columns like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fieldname">
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. On ASPxDataGridView select `EditTemplate` and select the required column and drag required control on `DataItemTemplate`

Answer (score 1):

```
 <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:CheckBox Text="text" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
```